# How can I make this cases match with regex?

Tags: css, regex

I need to match CSS as string.

1. I don't want any `#` character (Id).
2. Needs to match anything that includes as separate words `"body"`, `"li"`, `"ol"`, `"ul"`.
3. Needs to detect the word alone `"body"`, `"li"`, `"ol"`, `"ul"`.
4. Needs to detect the word among others i.e: `"selector li"`.
5. Needs to skip if a word contains `"li, ol, ul"` as part of it. For example `"lololol"` shouldn't match it.

I attempted doing it like this:

```
/^(\s)*|ol|ul|body|#|li|$/g
```

But is still not matching properly.

I'm using `https://regex101.com/` to test it.

Comment: i see :( can you help me solve it?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eR3wN2/2 see in there that i wrote some random css to make it match and i don't want for example to make lololol match with "ol", I need the "ol" literal only with or without space on both sides, same for other matches body, #, ol, li, ul.

Comment: This? _https://regex101.com/r/eR3wN2/3_

Comment: Yes!!! :) thanks! put it as an answer! and i will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use *\b* to delimit the word boundary:

```
^(\s)*|\bol\b|ul|body|#|li|$(\s)*
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/eR3wN2/3)